# Mongoose deleting object ($pull) in Array does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I'm trying to delete an object inside an array in my DB using the `$pull` in Mongoose but does not work.

This is my attempt:

```
const listSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    items: []
});

const List = mongoose.model("list", listSchema);

const itemDeleted = req.body.checkbox;
//I get here the ID of the object inside the array
const itemListDeleted = req.body.listDeleted;
// Here the name of the object that contains the array
```

```
List.findOneAndUpdate({name:itemListDeleted},{$pull:{items:{_id: itemDeleted}}},function (err,foundList) {
        if (foundList){
            res.redirect("/"+ itemListDeleted);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
})
```

I searched for solutions and everybody recommends using `$Pull` but in my case, it doesn't work. I log the const and all things appear to be right.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try it with just .update instead of .findOneAndUpdate?

Comment: Can you add your schema models to the question?

Comment: Convert `itemDeleted` to objectId using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(itemDeleted)`